# Custom Providers & Design Patterns

Tags: c#, design-patterns, asp.net-membership, asp.net-profiles

I am using ASP.NET 2.0 and its various providers. 
I have overridden most of the methods I need and
have the following custom providers:

ProjectMembershipProvider
ProjectProfileProvider
ProjectRoleProvider

In the design of my project, my intention was to 
wrap the custom providers in a facade - style 
design - mixing and matching profiling, membership, 
and roles in API methods to simplify things for 
developers.

But, I am finding that a lot of the methods 
in my custom providers don't need to change, 
really. And, it seems silly to wrap a stand-alone
method in another method that does exactly the 
same thing.

So - is my approach wrong? Or, should I allow 
end - users to instantiate the custom providers
when needed and the mix/match api when needed? 
This seems a bit redundant to me but I can't 
see another way.

Advice appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I wrote a custom provider set, I simply inherited from the existing asp.net providers and would overide any methods that needed custom logic.

I also used .Net [reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) to look into the existing  asp.net providers code, just to make sure there wasn't any dependancies I had to worry about.
Hope that helps